# can't update this so this will show the directory listing of a given directory in a column format

Tags: c++, operating-system, filesystems

```
 #include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
#include <dirent.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
using namespace std;
 int main()   
 {
    ifstream fin;
    string dir, filepath;
    int num;
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *dirp;
    struct stat filestat;
    
    cout << "dir to get files of: " << flush;
    getline( cin, dir );  // gets everything the user ENTERs 
    
    dp = opendir( dir.c_str() );
    if (dp == NULL)
        {
        cout << "Error(" << errno << ") opening " << dir << endl; 
        return errno;     
        }
    while ((dirp = readdir( dp )))
         {
         filepath = dir + "/" + dirp->d_name;
         // If the file is a directory (or is in some way invalid) we'll skip it
         if (stat( filepath.c_str(), &filestat )) continue;
         if (S_ISDIR( filestat.st_mode ))         continue;
          // read a single number from the file and display it     
         fin.open( filepath.c_str() );
         if (fin >> num)
            cout << filepath << ": " << num << endl;          
            fin.close(); 
 
 
    }   
    closedir( dp );   
    return 0;  
     }
```

I am facing difficulty to update this c++ code so this will show the directory listing of a given directory in a column format showing the File Name, File Size, and File Rights (Read only, Write Only, Both) and Last Accessed Time and date.

Comment: what difficulty are you facing?

Comment: i want to get File name ,file size but when i run this code no output is displayed after entering the path of the directory